# React useCallback hook for map rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, usecallback

When passing callback to component, I should use `useCallback` hook to return a memoized callback (to prevent unneeded renders):

```
import doSomething from "./doSomething";
const FrequentlyRerenders = ({ id }) => {
  const onEvent = useCallback(() => doSomething(id), [id]);
  return (
    <ExpensiveComponent onEvent={ onEvent } />
  );
};
```

But what if I am using map? for example:

```
import doSomething from "./doSomething";
const FrequentlyRerendersMap = ({ ids }) => {
  return ids.map(id => {
    const onEvent = useCallback(() => doSomething(id), [id]);
    return (
      <ExpensiveComponent key={id} onEvent={ onEvent } />
    );
  });
};
```

How should I properly use `useCallback`? Is the above the right way to pass multiple callbacks? Is it really works and know to memioze every callback according to an item of an array?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Convert the returned mapped JSX into a component and then you can useCallback without problems

```
import doSomething from "./doSomething";
const MappedComponent =(props) => {
   const onEvent = useCallback(() => doSomething(props.id), []);
   return (
      <ExpensiveComponent onEvent={ onEvent } />
   );
}

const FrequentlyRerendersMap = ({ ids }) => {
  return ids.map(id => {
    return <MappedComponent key={id} id={id} />
  });
};
```

Comment: I thought about it, but I can't due to system architecture. Is there a way to fix it without creating a new component?

Comment: How is it a system architecture change. You create a component to optimise on performance.The other way to handle it would involve you making a change in ExpensiveComponent whereby you pass on the id to it as a prop along with doSomething and call it from within ExpensiveComponent

Comment: For that matter, you could use [`memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) on `MappedComponent` and avoid `useCallback()` altogether.

Comment: yes, but this does not work for the children prop, (for items like <Marker>, that is a common child to a Google map. How can one memo() component children? Without this, the map flickers (due to rerendering).

Answer (score -2):

This is now expressly discouraged in the docs.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level

### Old answer

The answer to re architect is sidestepping the question IMO. Though, I think creating a new component is probably a good idea.

To answer the question though, your code:

```js
import doSomething from "./doSomething";
const FrequentlyRerendersMap = ({ ids }) => {
  return ids.map(id => {
    const onEvent = useCallback(() => doSomething(id), [id]);
    return (
      <ExpensiveComponent key={id} onEvent={ onEvent } />
    );
  });
};
```

Is actually what you would want to do to memoize in a map. I don't know the implementation of useCallback, but it should add very little memory overhead. A stackFrame, and whatever they do to reduce the array into some kind of key for the memoized function.

Unless your working on some with a TON of elements, EG react virtualized components unlimited scrolling, you are realistically safe to useCallback the way you are. In fact, the small memory overhead is probably a much cheaper price than the rerender of all of those components.

Comment: I am not sure what will be the behaviour in case of a list change.

Comment: If you pass a different id in the array of dependencies, it should return a different function.

Comment: This gives me an error: `React Hook "useCallback" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks`

Comment: @Tom 

Might be that it changed with the react version? Or you have this logic nested inside a useCallback?

Comment: This pattern is not expressly discouraged in the docs though https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level

Comment: @EricWooley the documentation you linked explicitly says "Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.", and the .map's callback is a nested function.

Comment: @Tom 

I dupred, I meant to say "*now* expressly..."

Sorry!